# node mongodb error bubbling & propagation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling

I have an issue with `Node.js` where my `MongoClient.connect()` function needs to propagate a thrown error back up to main; however, the error is getting lost and is interpreted as an `uncaughtException`.

```
var ErrorHandler = require('./bin/lib/error.js').ErrorHandler;

//throw new ErrorHandler('Throwing something random.', 'BadRequest', 400); // <-- this works, and throws error as expected!!

// verify that user doesn't already exist.
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', function(err, db){
    if (err) throw new Error( err );                    
    db.collection('users')
      .findOne({'email': useremail}, function(err,doc){
            throw new ErrorHandler('User already exists!', 'BadRequest', 400); // <-- this does not work, and error gets lost as an <anonymous> function error event
       });                              
});
```

I'm assuming the error is getting lost because the internal callback that I'm providing to `.findOne()` does not know about the `ErrorHandler` function I have created to extend the core `Error` class; however, I don't know how to rectify the issue and allow me to still call errors using the custom `ErrorHandler()` function from the results of a `mongodb` call like `mongodb.open()`.  Any ideas how to get the error to propagate back up through the callbacks so I can call `ErrorHandler()` from the script it is "required" in?

**UPDATE**

The main `server.js` file which is instantiating the entire server object invokes the following at the bottom to listen for other `uncaughtExceptions` and `SIGTERM` events:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
   console.error(err.stack); 
   n.server.close();
}).on('SIGTERM', function(){
   n.server.close(); 
});
```

When the error gets lost it propagates up to here. And executes in the `.on('uncaughtException',...` block which logs the entire errorstack as expected, it just doesn't get caught where I want it to get caught in my server object.

The actual `console.error(err.stack)` prints the following in this instance:

```
BadRequest: User already exists!
at new Error (<anonymous>)
at ErrorHandler (/home/cfarmer/dev/norad/bin/lib/error.js:4:18)
at /home/cfarmer/dev/norad/routes.js:118:13
at handleCallback (/home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at /home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1353:5
at handleCallback (/home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at /home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:670:5
at handleCallback (/home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:154:5)
at nextFunction (/home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:675:5)
at /home/cfarmer/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:588:7
```

Thanks

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @usandfriends check my UPDATE in my OP.  That may help shed some light.

Comment: My thought now is that this is related to the asynchronous nature of the `mongodb` library.  My server response triggers and sends back to the user before the `MongoClient.connect(...)` syntax even finishes running; then when the error is throw, it is uncaught because the connection has already been torn down and the try/catch block has exited already...

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Also, how exactly does `ErrorHandler` propagate errors back to `main`?

Comment: @usandfriends, no I haven't figured out a solution yet.  ErrorHandler simply extends the typical `Error` class by implementing `var err = Error.apply(this, arguments);` I also extend `ErrorHandler.prototype` with the following: `ErrorHandler.prototype = Error.prototype;` Then I simply add some extra criteria that I'm looking to capture, like a custom error code and error name, etc.

Comment: This issue is isolated to `mongodb` calls.  The `mongodb` calls are the only functions that my server response does not wait for.

Comment: How are you trying to catch your custom error?

Comment: I have a try/catch block in my main `server.js` script which `requires()` and in the try block calls the script that does the `mongodb` call.  In the catch block I execute `response.emit('error', e);`.  Then in `response.on('error', function(response){...})` I have `response.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );`

Comment: But I think we are not focusing on the right part of the issue.  Yes, my OP is related to `ErrorHandler` and throwing errors; however, the same issue exists if I were to attempt to return a valid value from inside a `MongoClient.connect(...)`.  Response will return, then `MongoClient` will return; causing the receiving to receive an unhandled response, because moments before, it had already received a response.

Comment: The only way to `catch` these errors is through `uncaughtException` callback. Instead, try passing an error function as a callback that gets called when there is an error. Instead of `throw new ErrorHandler(...)`, you would call `return errorHandler(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch a global error with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186146/how-to-catch-a-global-error-with-nodejs)